# Do the two given sentences mean the same?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-choice, restrictive-clauses

**"I have a few poems, and i'd like to know what people make of them."**

Now, if i were to convey what's conveyed in the sentence above, could i say **"I have a few poems i'd like to know what people make of."**?
Would it be grammatically correct, and convey the same meaning as the sentence used above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not expressing the same idea.

> I have three dogs and they are good at hunting.
>
> I have three dogs good at hunting.

In the first, the speaker has only three dogs.  In the second, he may have three dogs or ten dogs, we do not know which it is; all we know is that of the dogs he has, only three are good at hunting.

In the version without "and", the clause "good at hunting" is a reduced restrictive clause modifying, or qualifying, or adding definition to the noun phrase "three dogs":

**I have {three dogs good at hunting}.**

He may have some other number of dogs who are not good at hunting. Or he may have no other dogs.  All we know is the unified concept {three dogs (who are) good at hunting}.

In the original example:

{a few poems {i'd like to know what people make of}  }

the reduced restrictive clause is {i'd like to know what people make of}. He may have many other poems he wishes to keep private; but in the first sentence with "and", he has those few poems and only those few poems.